Rendering a Leaflet map in Flutter - flutter_webview vs fleaflet
In my app, I currently have a Leaflet map rendered using flutter_webview - loading a static HTML file and making JS channel calls for various updates. It seems to work fine most of the time; there are some issues of inconsistencies between Android and iOS, and some  limitations with the JS communication (ex. rendering GeoTiff from files). It's nice to be able to work directly with the web version of Leaflet, but it seems the overhead is sometimes too noticeable when it comes to memory usage, thus a laggy/unresponsive map.
My map currently loads custom geoJson overlay layers, ArcGIS layers with Esri Leaflet, and a couple leaflet plugins - leaflet-draw, leaflet.offline.
I've been following the fleaflet package which brings Leaflet to Flutter as a standalone widget, and so my question is what might be some of the benefits/drawbacks to making the switch.
